# How secure is the Note field in a Joomla Article?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'd like to know how secure is the Note field in a Joomla Article? I'd like to put a Note in there just for the Joomla Administrator to see. Is there any likelyhood this could become visible elsewhere such as on the front end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **front-end Article Edit form** in the Joomla core `/components/com_content/tmpl/form/edit.php` renders the note field using `<?php echo $this->form->renderField('note'); ?>` (Joomla 3 in line 109, Joomla 4 line 110). A user that has access to the edit forms, will be able to see the content of that field.

Furthermore **the API in Joomla 4** `/api/components/com_content/src/View/Articles/JsonapiView.php` retrieves that note field too. So if you re-use articles from your Joomla site via the API on other web applications/sites, the note field will be available and can be displayed on the other site/application.

In case you use **non-core extensions**: those might have the possibility of retrieving and displaying all kind of fields from your Joomla database and/or an article object.